# C# : How to convert .pptx to images?

Tags: image-processing, powerpoint

How to convert .pptx to images?
I want to get the image of each .pptx page

Answer (score 2):

I got it.

```
string str1 = @"C:\Users\prince\Desktop\PRINCE-PC 11-12-2553 14.07.57\SlideImages";

string str = @"C:\Users\prince\Desktop\PRINCE-PC 11-12-2553 14.07.57\slide.ppt";

Application pptApplication = new Application();
Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open(str, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
pptPresentation.SaveAs(str1, PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsJPG, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
pptPresentation.Close();
```

str1 = OutputFolder
str = powerpoint's filepath

Comment: Great to hear it is sorted. You can accept your own answer by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down arrows on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that one of the options of saving the pretension for the web will create images out of the slides.
Check it out.

AT power point 2010 you have save as JPG. it does what you ask.